# Error Implementing Breadth First Search using adjacency list In C++

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search, adjacency-list

I am trying to implement code for breadth first search using adjacency list in C++ . But it shows segmentation fault error. I do not know where and what have I done wrong in my code. I tried everything I know to fix this but i could not. it would be really useful for me if anyone helped with the fault in my code.

It gives error only when I input a complex graph but when I input a simple graph it gives the answer and I don`t know whats wrong.

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include<iterator>
using namespace std;


class graph 
{ 
    int v;    // No. of vertices 
    list<int> *adj; //pointer to the list    
public: 
    graph(int v);  // Constructor 
    void addedge(int s, int d);  
    void BFS(int s);
    void s_d(int v);
};


graph::graph(int vertice) 
{ 
    this->v=vertice; 
    adj = new list<int>[v]; //adj is list pointer which is now pointing to the first list in an array of lists 
} 


void graph::addedge(int s, int d) 
{ 
    adj[s].push_back(d); // Add value d to list number s. 
//  adj[d].push_back(s);
}


void graph::BFS(int s)
{
 bool *visited = new bool[v];   //created a bool arr of size same that of vertices v(v declared in class)
 for(int i=0;i<v;i++)           //make all vertices as not visited at first
    {
     visited[i]=false;
    }
 list<int> queue;       //create a list queue to store all to visit nodes
 visited[s]=true;       //mark the current node as visited bcoz we are on that node currently
 queue.push_back(s);    //put current node in queue 
 list<int>::iterator i; //make an iterator i which will iterate through the list

 while(!queue.empty())
    {
     s=queue.front();
     cout<<s<<' ';       //printing in ur visited order
     queue.pop_front();  //pop and display the visited vertice
     //down here in for loop we iterating through the elements inside the lists first list,second ,third...
     for(i=adj[s].begin(); i != adj[s].end();i++) //iterate i(iterator) from pointer adj current list number fully till <NULL
        {
         if(!visited[*i])  
            {
             visited[*i] = true;   //if the roots adjacent we looking at now aint visited then make it visited and put into queue 
             queue.push_back(*i);
            }
        }
    }
}


void graph::s_d(int v)  //source and destination for edges input
{
 int s,d,source,edges;      //s is source and "source" is starting vertice for bfs
 cout<<"enter the number of edges present : ";
 cin>>edges;
 cout<<"enter the source and destinations for your vertices : "<<'\n';
 for(int i=0;i<edges;i++)
    {
     cout<<"edge number "<<i+1<<" enter : "<<'\n';
     cin>>s>>d;
     addedge(s,d);
    }
 cout<<"enter the starting source : ";
 cin>>source;
 BFS(source);
} 


int main()
{
    int v;
    cout<<"enter the number of vertices for your graph : ";
    cin>>v;
    graph g(v);
    g.s_d(v);
    cout<<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the input which gives answer:

`vertices 5 and edges 7`

`inputs |0 1|0 4|1 4|1 3|1 2|4 3|3 2|` gives answer : `0 1 4 3 2 (source start 0)`

Input which gives segmentation fault error:

`vertices 6 edges 8 (source start 1)`

`inputs |1 2|1 6|2 3|2 5|3 4|3 5|5 4|5 6| error segmentation fault(core dumped)`

Comment: If you use STL already, you might as well continue with it. Replace list<int> *adj with list<list<int> > adj or vector<vector<int> > adj.

Comment: Having 6 vertices, you should be indexing them from `0` to `5`, but instead, you put an edge `1-6`, which is beyond `adj` range.

Comment: thanks for help i understood what was wrong with my inputs.

Comment: running in GDB, you are segfaulting on this line inside ::BFS `if(!visited[*i])`

Comment: @HappyKeyboard thankyou! i also noticed the same. nothing is wrong with the code but the way of inputs itself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the others pointed out, it's indexing problem.

```
adj = new list<int>[v + 1]; // add + 1
```

in line 21 in the graph::graph() function, changing `v` to `v + 1` makes your input work.

the segmentation fault happened because you assigned V elements (from index 0 to index V-1) and tried to access (V+1)th element(which has index V)